# "Network configuration timed out: please verify settings"

Tags: networking, 18.04

I am running into an issue with my Dell PowerEdgee R610. I am new to the Ubuntu server world but have ran ubuntu desktop many of times.

When trying to run the network configuration, DHCP is enabled on the server BIOS but for some reason is not pulling an IP address to Eno1-4.

I tried setting a static from what I have in my router for the server,

```
Subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
Ipv4 addr: 192.168.1.118
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Name Server:8.8.8.8
```

I set static routes in my router.

Any ideas?

I also wanted to add that my LCC for the server does ping out to websites properly. It has an internet connection that can do so.

Image for troubleshooting:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/MWKNIwJ]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/MWKNIwJ]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/gMqeVit]

`dhclient -v`

[image: https://imgur.com/a/2YwGqCw]

They were too large to upload to the post, and i couldnt find a way to save the CLI session on the bootable drive.

Comment: Where did you set the static IP? Netplan?? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I set the static in the router for the server. I tried setting a static in the UEFI but it did not do anything.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138489/ubuntu-server-19-04-not-installing-ethernet-firmware-on-dell-poweredge-r610/1138769#1138769

Comment: @heynnema I tried running the `script` command to export a file of it onto the bootable but It does not save. Do you know a command I can use to export that info for you?

Comment: @chili555 I read through that, i did not have the same output that person had, I wish it fixed this :(

Comment: Please post: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also run: `sudo dhclient -v` Tell us which interface (eno1? eno3? etc.) gets a temporary DHCP address. I will then propose a solution.

Comment: @Neman16 I'm not aware of any script. However, if you open a terminal, execute the commands, select the output, copy it to the clipboard, you can then edit your question and paste it in using the clipboard.

Comment: @chili555, image links added. Also the `sudo dhclient -v` returned that each eth0-1 is "Network Down"

Comment: @heynnema, image added.

Comment: I'm certain that the reason that dhclient returned 'network is down' is because each and every interface is shown as DISABLED. Does it help if you do: `sudo ip link set eno1 up` and then try again: `sudo dhclient -v` No need to post an Imgur; just tell us if there is any imrovement.

Comment: I already tried the `sudo ip link set eno1 up` Returns: "RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory" @chili555 Added the image of the DHclient command

Comment: I will propose an incomplete and temporary answer. I will amend it as we find more details and learn more results.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I really appreciate it. At this point I have no idea what to research or look into... Thank you so much for your time and I look forward to getting this fixed!

Comment: In reviewing your uploads, it looks like all the ethernet devices 1) have a driver, 2) are all disabled, 3) none have a link... indicating a possible cabling issue. This may look different if you've done some/all of chili555's answer. So please describe the cabling, from each ethernet port, all the way to the hub/switch/router/modem.

Comment: @Neman16 remember to tell me about the cabling.

Answer (score 0):

Dell PowerEdgee R610 may require additional, custom firmware. The installation should complain about the missing firmware with relevant messages, that may tell you what you're looking for.

If such messages does not show up, then you may want to try to use lshw to find your service tag.

```
sudo lshw | less
```

You should see something like:

```
product: PowerEdge R610
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: XXXXXXX
```

Your serial will be there. You can copy it and paste at https://www.dell.com/support/ to find proper drivers.

You will not find Ubuntu drivers on Dell site probably, but you're looking for .bin files reated to Network devies.

Comment: I will give this a try and see what I can do! Is there any way to run cli for ubuntu while it is trying to install?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/735410/how-to-open-cli-during-installation

Comment: So i wasn't able to find any drivers that seemed to affect the NIC. I did open the CLI though and was able to locate my NICs Logical names Eno1-4. When I tried a `sudo ifconfig eno1 up`, it returned `SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory exists`.

When I run a `ifconfig eno1` it does show that it is there.

Comment: Seems to be driver related after some digging, I cannot find any drivers that would pertain to Ubuntu on Dell's website, would you possibly recommend any that may work?

Comment: The drivers appear to be there.

Comment: @heynnema Qlogic Gigabit ethernet driver V2.2.6 installed on the server, still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later, ifup/down, implemented by /etc/network/interfaces, is replaced by netplan. Therefore, please revert the faulty entries. From the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Take out all the entries except:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Next, let's clean up your netplan file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Change the file to read:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
```

Netplan is very specific about indentation and spacing. Please proofread carefully twice. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

After these changes, reboot and let us see:

```
sudo dhclient -v
```

We hope will find out which interface has the ethernet cable attached and then amend the yaml file accordingly if it isn't eno1.

Comment: Changed the config, returned RTNETlink answers: No such file or directory D:

Comment: May we see the Imgur? Also, in sudo lshw -C network, are all interfaces still disabled?

Comment: I got the same exact results from before, still disabled..

Comment: Let's see if we can find out why. `dmesg | grep -e eno -e bnx` Is there an option to enable/disable ethernet in the BIOS?

Comment: The BIOS has ethernet on, I was able to confirm this by a ping test from the LCC in the Dell UEFI. It pinged out to the internet. It seems to be only Ubuntu that can't manage to use it.

Comment: Any results here? `dmesg | grep -e eno -e bnx`?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem like you. After boot I type
`dmesg | grep bnx2`

`bnx2: Can't load firmware file "bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1b.fw"`

I find an answer in
[Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5716 Ethernet controller unclaimed after update to 16.04 server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934832/broadcom-netxtreme-ii-bcm5716-ethernet-controller-unclaimed-after-update-to-16-0/934849?r=SearchResults#934849)

Download the firmware and copy to my server, and `modprobe bnx2`